# Black Screen before Login Screen Ubuntu 16.10 VirtualBox

Tags: gnome, virtualbox, login, 16.10, ubuntu-gnome

I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 16.10 on a Virtualbox(5.1.14 r112924) machine. When I boot, there are no errors, but right when the graphical login screen is shown, there's just a black screen. I can press enter to select the first user and enter my password, but I can't actually see anything until I am logged into the desktop.

I have tried the GRUB "nomodeset" option, but that doesn't even start a graphical interface. I have also installed guest additions with no results.

Anybody know how I can fix this?